# Answers show a placeholder instead of my profile picture

Tags: bug

For the last day or so, my answers have shown a placeholder image instead of my profile picture. This might have started when the website received its makeover.

### There is a placeholder instead of my profile image

[image]

### Hovering shows my profile image

[image]